# How to make divs rise up from other divs?

Tags: javascript, css, class, html

I know how to stack divs on top of divs by doing `position:absolute` for the parent and `position:relative` for the children, but how can I make a div "rise up" from another div? An example of what I want to achieve is [here](http://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/17765-kavinsky-outrun/). Scroll to the bottom and hover your mouse over the artwork.

Comment: have you tried z-index.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMl

```
<div id="pic">
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#pic {
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#pic div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    background: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;

}
```

JQuery

```
$('#pic').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('div').stop(true, true).animate({
            'bottom': '+=50'
        }, 100);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('div').stop(true, true).animate({
            'bottom': '-=50'
        }, 100);
    }
);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6eLa/2/

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is absolute position that pop-up in a relative positioned box, for example:

```
<div class="featured-image">
  <div class="caption">
    <p>This is where your text goes</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now that you have that, you'll want to make the caption invisible unless scrolled over. So, a simple way to do this with just CSS is:

```
.featured-image { position:relative; width:300px; height: 400px; }
.caption { position:absolute; bottom:0; display:none; }
.feature-image:hover > .caption { display:block; }
```

The last line makes it seen when you mouse-over the image.

Then you could animate it with jQuery easily. That appears to be what they're using.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".caption").hide();
});
var show = function() {
    $(".caption", this).stop(true, true).show(500)
};
var hide = function() {
    $(".caption", this).stop(true, true).hide(500);
};  
    $(".featured-image").hover(show, hide);
```

Comment: By the way, to make the CSS play nice with the jQuery, you should include the `display:` values inside <noscript>.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce yourself to jQuery and z-index.

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

The trick here is slidedown will make your top div slide down. The only thing that comes to my mind, is instead of expanding that bottom div up, do the opposite. Get the top div, and have it slide-up, while the other div is displayed behind it. It should give the appearance of the bottom div 'sliding-up'.

Note, sorry if this doesn't work. I'm actually not sure if you can get it to slide only halfway up instead of all the way...good luck though!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS for that, just use css3 transitions.

Comment: please provide details or an example of how to do this using css3 transitions.